# Azure ML: how to use remote location as code path?

Tags: azureml-python-sdk, azuremlsdk

I am using Azure ML python SDK v2 to submit the job. The code parameter at "command" is pointed to the local "./source" path.

```
train_func = command(
       environment="AzureML-sklearn-1.0-ubuntu20.04-py38-cpu:33",
       command='python myfunc.py ...',
       code='./source',
       ...
   )
```

How to use remote location as code path in the above example? I read the reference [azure-ai-ml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-ai-ml/azure.ai.ml?view=azure-python) and it shows the code can be a remote location:

`code Optional[Union[str, PathLike]] The source code to run the job. Can be a local path or "http:", "https:", or "azureml:" url pointing to a remote location.`

I tried use the path[text](https://stackoverflow.com)-like "azureml://" from AzureDataStore URI but not working.

Comment: Hey to use a remote location as the code path, you can provide a URL pointing to the remote location

Comment: @MohamedAzarudeenZ  Thanks for comments. Can you can give an example? I tried to use the uri path-like "azureml://subscriptions/xxxx/resourcegroups/xxx/workspaces/xxx/datastores/xxx/paths/local/src/" but not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have uploaded the source code using below code snippet:

```py
from azure.ai.ml.entities import Data
from azure.ai.ml.constants import AssetTypes

my_path = "./src"
# set the version number of the data asset
v1 = "initial"

my_data = Data(
    name="source",
    version=v1,
    description="Code",
    path=my_path,
    type=AssetTypes.URI_FOLDER,
)
try:
    data_asset = ml_client.data.get(name="source", version=v1)
    print(f"Data asset already exists. Name: {my_data.name}, version: {my_data.version}")
except:
    ml_client.data.create_or_update(my_data)
    print(f"Data asset created. Name: {my_data.name}, version: {my_data.version}")
```

Once uploaded, I have used `Storage URI` as the remote code path.
[image]

With this, the job is executed successfully.
[image]

Comment: Thanks. still not work on my case. It will automatically report "/path/https:/xxx" can't find. It seems that my code treats it as "workpath/code" no matter "code" is starting with https:// or azureml://.